# Reading image from database using Data Layer Access

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, image, webforms

Using Data Layer Access to Insert in Database. Also, using Select statement to get Data from Database. 
When DataGrid is filled with info, there is no Image - I do not know how to use to convert bytes into Image.

DataGrid is filled this way :

```
BooksTableAdapter booksTableAdapter = new BooksTableAdapter();
GridView1.DataSource = booksTableAdapter.GetEverythingFromBooks();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

It works perfectly, but i do not see Image.

Whole Insert statement goes this way :

```
BooksTableAdapter insertAdapter = new BooksTableAdapter();
int NewBook = Convert.ToInt32(insertAdapter.InsertBook(Titletxt.Text, Categorytxt.Text, ISBNtxt.Text, Descriptiontxt.Text, pic));
```

Also, not sure that converting image is working properly.

Comment: Where is your code for the `GridView`? How are you setting the value returned in your dataset to the image server control?